# How to convert JSON String to HTML Table in Flask?

Tags: html, json, flask

I am trying to convert json to html table but getting error UndefinedError: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'items'.
I am getting below json from response and I am storing it into d5,

['{"pf":"K"', '"users":1', '"evennts":1}', '{"pf":"A"', '"users":7', '"evennts":7}', '{"pf":"I"', '"users":3', '"evennts":3}']

follwing is my code,

```
finalJson = json.dumps(d5)
    table_data = (json2html.convert(json = finalJson))
    return render_template_string('''
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td> PF </td> 
                <td> users </td>
                <td> events </td>
            </tr>

    {% for pf, users,events in table_data.items() %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{ pf }}</td> 
                <td>{{ users }}</td>
                <td>{{ events }}</td>
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
''', table_data=table_data)
```

I want to convert that json into html table like,

| pf | users | events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K | 1 | 1 |
| I | 3 | 3 |
| A | 7 | 7 |

Comment: Why do the data need to be json format? You could just keep it as original form.

Comment: @EpicChen I am getting that json from response and i want to use it

Comment: The response is ['{"pf":"K"', '"users":1', '"evennts":1}', '{"pf":"A"', '"users":7', '"evennts":7}', '{"pf":"I"', '"users":3', '"evennts":3}'] or [{"pf":"K", "users":1, "evennts":1}, {"pf":"A", "users":7, "evennts":7}, {"pf":"I", "users":3, "evennts":3}]? Actually, the first one is wrong josn format if you post it to  http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: actually  that reponse is output of spark dataframe

Comment: I have done some surveys, I think that the output of spark dataframe should be ['{"pf":"K", "users":1, "evennts":1},{"pf":"A", "users":7, "evennts":7},{"pf":"I", "users":3, "evennts":3}'] ? http://www.devrats.com/spark-and-json/

Comment: yes i am getting same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have checked above, try this

```py
        d5 = ['{"pf":"K", "users":1, "events":1},{"pf":"A", "users":7, "events":7},{"pf":"I", "users":3, "events":3}']
        # convert spark json array result to a list.
        finalJson = json.loads("[" + d5[0] + "]") 
    
        return render_template_string('''
        <style>
        table, th, td {
             border: 1px solid black;
        }
        table {
            width:80%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td {
            text-align: center
        }
        th:first-child, td:first-child {
            text-align: left
        }
        th:last-child, td:last-child {
            text-align: right
        }
        </style>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> PF </th> 
                    <th> users </th>
                    <th> events </th>
                </tr>
    
        {% for row in table_data %}
    
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ row['pf'] }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ row['users'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row['events'] }}</td>
                </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    ''', table_data=finalJson)
```

You could also feel free to modify styles to what you want.

Comment: Do you notice that d5 is not a string? d5 is a array. [ xxxxxxx ], You mean your d5 = "['{"pf":"K", "users":1, "evennts":1},{"pf":"A", "users":7, "evennts":7},{"pf":"I", "users":3, "evennts":3}']"? The goal is that modify the string to a valid json string before call json.load

Comment: Thanks, got that. but still there is one issue.   In PF column I am getting rows like events events events, in Users column i am getting pf and in events column getting users.

Comment: Maybe you could provide  the screenshot?

Comment: can you give me your email id, I will send you screenshot

Comment: Sent you a mail. Please check

Comment: I have modified the code, main is at the {% for row in table_data %} loop part. Moreover, the original spell of the field 'events' is incorrect, I have modified it from 'evennts' to 'events'.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
d5='[{"pf":"K","users":1,"events":1},{"pf":"A","users":7,"events":7},{"pf":"I","users":3,"events":3}]'
finalJson = json.loads(d5)

return render_template_string('''
<table>
        <tr>
            <td> PF </td> 
            <td> users </td>
            <td> events </td>
        </tr>

{% for pf, users,events in finalJson %}

        <tr>
            <td>{{ pf }}</td> 
            <td>{{ users }}</td>
            <td>{{ events }}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
''', finalJson=finalJson)
```

First, the string d5 should have correct json format.
Second, if you want to covert string to json, you can use json.loads (not dumps)

finalJson is 'List'. So you can iterate it without items() funciton.

Comment: I think your json is also invalid